# How to map character to variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to make a word generator, which displays your input in a big font in the console. For this, I need to print the respective variable based on the character's in the user's input (e.g. if the user types `"a"`, then the variable `a` should be printed). How do I do so? This is my code:

```py
a = [
    "@@@@@",
    "@   @",
    "@   @",
    "@@@@@",
    "@   @",
    "@   @",
    "@   @"
]

b = [
    "@@@@ ",
    "@   @",
    "@   @",
    "@@@@ ",
    "@   @",
    "@   @",
    "@@@@ "
]

c = [
    "@@@@@",
    "@    ",
    "@    ",
    "@    ",
    "@    ",
    "@    ",
    "@@@@@"
]

input_word = input("Which word would you like to display?")
for c in input_word:
    # How do I print the variable whose name is equal to the value of `c` here?
    pass
```

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Why do you put unnecessary `()` around some of the strings in your lists?

Comment: @WoutervandenBroeke I'm sure if you read it, you'll find it helps you. If it doesn't, ask us why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dictionary that maps each letter to the corresponding list:

```
letter_map = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, ...}
in = input("What letter?")
print(letter_map[in[0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`word` contains the word

1. make it a dictionary where the letter is the key and the values are in an array: `letters = {'a': ["@@@@@", "@   @", "@   @", "@@@@@", "@   @", "@   @", "@   @"], ...}`
2. iterate over the count of items in the array with `range(7)` using `for`: `for row in range(7):`
3. iterate over the word letters, getting the mapped symbols: `for letter in word:`
4. join with a space: `outword += " " + letters[letter][row]`
5. finally join all lines with a newline

That should get you started. Feel free to try and post your results. We can help you once you have some code.

6. (optional) learn list comprehensions and come up with a one-liner for some unreadable fun

`print('\n'.join([' '.join([{'a': ["@@@@@", "@   @", "@   @", "@@@@@", "@   @", "@   @", "@   @"]  , 'b': ["@@@@ ", "@   @", "@   @", "@@@@ ", "@   @", "@   @", "@@@@ "]  , 'c': ["@@@@@", "@    ", "@    ", "@    ", "@    ", "@    ", "@@@@@"]  , 'd': ["@@@@ ", "@   @", "@   @", "@   @", "@   @", "@   @", "@@@@ "]  , 'e': ["@@@@@", "@    ", "@    ", "@@@@@", "@    ", "@    ", "@@@@@"]  , 'f': ["@@@@@", "@    ", "@    ", "@@@@@", "@    ", "@    ", "@    "]  , 'g': ["@@@@@", "@    ", "@    ", "@ @@@", "@   @", "@   @", "@@@@@"]  , 'h': ["@   @", "@   @", "@   @", "@@@@@", "@   @", "@   @", "@   @"]  , 'i': ["@@@@@", "  @  ", "  @  ", "  @  ", "  @  ", "  @  ", "@@@@@"]  , 'j': ["    @", "    @", "    @", "    @", "    @", "@   @", " @@@ "]      , 'k': ["@   @", "@  @ ", "@ @  ", "@@   ", "@ @  ", "@  @ ", "@   @"]  , 'l': ["@    ", "@    ", "@    ", "@    ", "@    ", "@    ", "@@@@@"]    , 'm': ["@   @", "@@ @@", "@ @ @", "@ @ @", "@   @", "@   @", "@   @"]}[l][i] for l in "abcdefghijklm"]) for i in range(7)]))`